# Break statement misplaced in while-loop

Tags: javascript, syntax, while-loop

I'd like to create a script that asks for the item you want from a list (array), check if the item is on stock, displays the inventory if your type "list" and quit the program (while loop) if you type "quit"

```js
while (true) { // endless loop
  var search = prompt('Type the item you are looking for, type "list" to display the inventory, type "quit" to exit te store.');
  search = search.toLowerCase;
}
if (search = 'quit') {
  break; // if the client types quit, they exit the store, loop ends
} else if search == 'list'{
  write('<p>We currently have ' + inventory.join(', ') + ' in stock.</p>');
} else if (inventory.indexOf(search) > - 1) {
  write('<p>Yes, we have ' + search + ' in our stock.</p>');
} else {
  write('<p>Sorry, we don\'t have ' + search + ' in our stock</p>');
}
```

The break statement is out of the loop but I don't really see where it should go ...

Any thoughts?

Comment: any errors in your developer tools console ... along the lines of `SyntaxError: unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch` ... oh, you wouldn't ... because your code never gets that far due to the endless while loop

Comment: also ... `=` assignment ... `==` and `===` test for equality

Comment: The whole `if` is misplaced.

Comment: Er, why don't you put the whole thing in the loop?  Don't you want to do something with the `prompt` result before looping again?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the entire "if" construct inside the "while" loop!

I.e., move the "}" from line 4 to the end of your code.

The "break" will then relate to the "while" construct.

Answer (score 0):

You have atleast three Errors in your code:

First the if is outside of the Loop.
second you miss brackets arround one if Statement.
Third in the first if Statement you miss the second equals sign

```js
var search='1';
while (true) { // endless loop
  var search = prompt('Type the item you are looking for, type "list" to display the inventory, type "quit" to exit te store.');
  search = search.toLowerCase;

if (search == 'quit') {
  break; // if the client types quit, they exit the store, loop ends
} else if (search == 'list'){
  write('<p>We currently have ' + inventory.join(', ') + ' in stock.</p>');
} else if (inventory.indexOf(search) > - 1) {
  write('<p>Yes, we have ' + search + ' in our stock.</p>');
} else {
  write('<p>Sorry, we don\'t have ' + search + ' in our stock</p>');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You had misplaced bracket and also missed == in the if statement;

```js
while (true) { // endless loop
  var search = prompt('Type the item you are looking for, type "list" to display the inventory, type "quit" to exit te store.');
  search = search.toLowerCase;

if (search == 'quit') {
  break; // if the client types quit, they exit the store, loop ends
} else if search == 'list'{
  write('<p>We currently have ' + inventory.join(', ') + ' in stock.</p>');
} else if (inventory.indexOf(search) > - 1) {
  write('<p>Yes, we have ' + search + ' in our stock.</p>');
} else {
  write('<p>Sorry, we don\'t have ' + search + ' in our stock</p>');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your data in the while loop and break it there, if needed.

I've also corrected errors and tested the script.

You can find in my comments details about the errors.

```js
while (true) { // endless loop
  var search = prompt('Type the item you are looking for, type "list" to display the inventory, type "quit" to exit te store.');
  search = search.toLowerCase();
      // After getting user input you want to check it and decide accordingly if
  // you want to stop the loop or you want to ask the user for input again
  if (search == 'quit') { // *** ERROR *** In your code you used a
// single = and that doesn't work for comparison in Javascript
    break; // if the client types quit, they exit the store, loop ends
  } else if (search == 'list') {// *** ERROR *** If you have more than a single if you need to always use parenthesis
    console.log('<p>We currently have ' + inventory.join(', ') + ' in stock.</p>');
  } else if (inventory.indexOf(search) > -1) {
    console.log('<p>Yes, we have ' + search + ' in our stock.</p>');
  } else {
    console.log('<p>Sorry, we don\'t have ' + search + ' in our stock</p>');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were several errors in your code, some syntactical such as missing parenthesis, or using only a single equal sign. The `break` keyword needs to be inside the loop, or it will have no loop to break out of.

However, if instead of the part where we say `if(!search) continue;` we said `if(!search) break;` you could break out of the loop by clicking cancel or entering an empty string, which makes more sense if you ask me.

```js
var inventory = ['tea','sugar'];
while (true) { // endless loop
  var search = prompt('Type the item you are looking for, type "list" to display the inventory, type "quit" to exit te store.');

  if(!search) continue;

  search = search.toLowerCase();

  if (search == 'quit') {
    break; // if the client types quit, they exit the store, loop ends
  } else if (search == 'list') {
    alert('<p>We currently have ' + inventory.join(', ') + ' in stock.</p>');
  } else if (inventory.indexOf(search) > -1) {
    alert('<p>Yes, we have ' + search + ' in our stock.</p>');
  } else {
    alert('<p>Sorry, we don\'t have ' + search + ' in our stock</p>');
  }
}
```